# How to delete a particular label from ltree in Postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, sql-update, postgresql-9.1

How to delete a particular label from `ltree` in Postgres table? I have a table?

Test table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (sno int, path ltree, userid int);

INSERT INTO tbl (sno, path, userid)
VALUES
  (1, '123',             123)
, (2, '123.101',         123)
, (3, '123.101.103',     123)
, (4, '123.101.103.105', 123)
, (5, '123.101.103.107', 123)
, (6, '123.102.104.106', 123)
, (7, '123.102.104.108', 123)
, (8, '123.102.104',     123)
, (9, '123.102',         123);
```

I want to pass a `userid` to a query, to remove it from every `path` in the table. For example, if I pass `101`, then `123.101.103` should update as `123.103`.

Is it possible to do this directly? Or shall I update `path` using path replace functions?

I tried the following select query from PHP, but it returns the error below. The same query works properly in phpPgAdmin!?

Query:

```
$selectPathq=pg_query($con,"select path from myschema.test where path @ '101'")
             or die('could not connect: '. pg_last_error($con));
```

Error:

> ```
> could not connect:
> ERROR: operator does not exist: myschema.ltree @ unknown at character 63
> HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
>       You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Comment: For readers. The magic *to workaround the **ugly "operator does not exist**" error* (why PostgreSQL not fixed it??)  is to use the replace of operator `@` by   **`operator(public.@)`** (or `@>` etc.) as explained in the answer. Not need other changes in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Fix error

To use the data type `ltree` and associated functions you need the additional module [`ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) installed.

By default, additional modules are installed to the schema `public`. If your current setting for `search_path` does not include the schema `public`, ltree operators are not found. Your error messages hints in this direction:

> ```
> ERROR: operator does not exist: myschema.ltree @ unknown at character 63
> ```

To verify, schema-qualify the ltree operator `@`:

```
SELECT path FROM tbl WHERE path operator(public.@) '101';
```

Does it work now?
If that's the root of the problem, you can also set your `search_path` properly. Check with:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Set with:

```
SET search_path = public; -- add more schemas as needed
```

[The manual about `search_path`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

#### UPDATE path

If I read your question right and you want to remove a certain item from the path of *all* rows:

```sql
UPDATE tbl t
SET    path = nu.path
FROM  (
   WITH x AS (
      SELECT sno, path, index(path, '101') AS i
      FROM   tbl
      WHERE  path ~ '*.101.*'
      )
   SELECT sno
        , subpath(path, 0, i)
          || CASE WHEN nlevel(path) > i+1 THEN subpath(path, i+1)
                  ELSE '' END AS path
   FROM x
   ) nu
WHERE nu.sno = t.sno;
```

(Note that since `path` is type `ltree`, the operator `~` in the expression `path ~ '*.101.*'` is *not* a regular expression match operator, but a special ltree match operator, and the right term is taken to be of type [`lquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.5). It matches any label path containing the label `101`.)

This would leave you with an empty path where you had just `101`. You could put this into a trigger `AFTER DELETE` to purge a certain item from all rows.

Comment: I tried following query, UPDATE test t SET path = nu.path FROM (WITH x AS (SELECT sno, path, index(path, '123') AS i FROM test WHERE  path ~ '*.104.*') SELECT sno,subpath(path, 0, i) || CASE WHEN nlevel(path) > i+1 THEN subpath(path, i+1) ELSE '' END AS path FROM x) nu WHERE nu.sno = t.sno; But it updates from "102.104.102.104.106" to "102.104.102.104.102.104.102.104.106"

Comment: @Ram: looks like you forgot to replace the 2nd occurrence of '123' in my example with '104'?

Comment: Yes,Thank you very much Erwin Brandstetter.I accepted and voted the answer.

Comment: Hi,  there are **an "elegant solution" for the  "operator does not exist"  error?**  The replace by `operator(public.@) ` is an ugly workaround... I try  `CREATE EXTENSION  ltree WITH   SCHEMA myschema`  with  pg9.5 but the `WITH`  seems ignored.